# Why does the head() method display more than the default 5 records after grouping?

Tags: python, pandas

After importing from CSV, I created the object cars.
`Cars.head()` returns the following 5 records, which is as expected

```
    car_names           mpg     cyl
0   Mazda RX4           21.0    6
1   Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0    6
2   Datsun 710          22.8    4
3   Hornet 4 Drive      21.4    6
4   Hornet Sportabout   18.7    8
```

Subsequently I created a new object cars_group sorting cars by cylinder, and tried calling the head() method again.

```
cars_group = cars.groupby(['cyl'])
cars_group.head()
```

However this time the output shows 15 records:

```
    car_names           mpg     cyl 
0   Mazda RX4           21.0    6   
1   Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0    6   
2   Datsun 710          22.8    4   
3   Hornet 4 Drive      21.4    6   
4   Hornet Sportabout   18.7    8   
5   Valiant             18.1    6   
6   Duster 360          14.3    8   
7   Merc 240D           24.4    4   
8   Merc 230            22.8    4   
9   Merc 280            19.2    6   
11  Merc 450SE          16.4    8   
12  Merc 450SL          17.3    8   
13  Merc 450SLC         15.2    8   
17  Fiat 128            32.4    4   
18  Honda Civic         30.4    4
```

Can somebody explain why this is happening? It seems like after sorting, the expected # of records (5) is multiplied by 3, which also coincidentally seems to be the number of unique cylinder values. I also noted that the order returned by `cars_group.head()` doesn't seem to be grouped by the number of cylinders, and instead retains the same order as originally imported from .csv.

Comment: Your code is calling groupby.head(), not df.head(). The former returns the first 5 rows of every group, so the total number of rows is #groups * 5 => 3 * 5 = 15.

Comment: `cars_group != cars_groups` is the typo in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: updated, good eye! it was a copying error. @cs95 seems to have the correct answer but i'm unable to accept since it's a comment and not a formal answer :(

Comment: No worries, you can write the answer yourself and then self-accept it after 2 days have passed from the time the question was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per cs95:

> Your code is calling groupby.head(), not df.head(). The former returns the first 5 rows of every group, so the total number of rows is #groups * 5 => 3 * 5 = 15.